# Rails jQuery/Ajax passing multiple files using API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, filepicker.io

I am using the FileStack API and filepicker gem. I have the JavaScript below that parses a JSON browser response and sends it to the create action of the Attachment controller I have with Rails. I am trying to get it so that it can handle multiple files being uploaded and thus, multiple attachment models being created, and at the end, the form being submitted and the multiple models being saved. This code works with one file being uploaded, but I am trying to get it to work with multiple ones being dragged and dropped in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%= simple_form_for @attachment, :html=> { id: 'file_stack_form' } do |f| %>

<%= f.filepicker_field :title, multiple: 'true', onchange: 'onUpload(event)' %>
<% end %>

<script>
  function onUpload(event) {
  var fileNumber = event.fpfiles.length;
  var url = event.fpfile.url;
  var name = event.fpfile.filename;
  for (var i = 0; i < fileNumber; i++) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    data: { "attachment[name]": name, "attachment[title]" : url },
    type: 'post',
    url: "/attachments"
  });
  success: $('#file_stack_form').submit();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What type of `:title` have this field? When I uploaded images with `carrierwave` I used json type for my PostgreSQL database to upload multiple files.

Comment: I am using the FileStack API and filepicker gem. I have a model Attachments with a column :title that stores the URL.